# jQuery strange delay behaviour

Tags: jquery, delay

I'm having strange error with `delay()`. I have website where I add images src on delay with function like that:

```
  $('.attachment-full').each(function(indexs) { 
var visible_pathz = $(this).attr('data-info');
$(this).delay(200*indexs).attr('src', visible_pathz).fadeIn(300);   
});
```

On home page It does work as expected, but on single page It just adds images src at the same time without any delay.

What did I do wrong here, or what do I miss ?

Comment: Delay works only for queue, like animations. `The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.` Try `var $this = $(this); setTimeout(function(){$this.attr('src', visible_pathz).fadeIn(300);}, 200*indexs);`

Comment: thanks for quick reply. So the question is why does It work on home page, then ?

Comment: The .fadeIn can be delayed(I beleive) the .attr can not and will happen immediately

Comment: @MateuszWinnicki I do not know what happens on your home page, as I do not see its code. Delay works only for the queue of the element, so if you assign the set of animations for one node, it has a queue and execution of those animations can be delayed. It does not delay `.attr` function, only can affect `fadeIn` animation.

Comment: thanks for further explaination ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery docs implicitly states that delay is **NOT** a timout and should use for animations ONLY

what you are trying to achive is that:

```
function doSomething()
{
   // place your code here
}

setTimeout(doSomething, 200);
```

### EDIT:

```
$('.attachment-full').each(function(indexs) 
{ 
    var visible_pathz = $(this).attr('data-info');

    setTimeout(function(e)
    {          
        e.attr('src', visible_pathz).fadeIn(300);

    }, 200 * indexs, $(this));
});
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply. So the question is why does It work on home page, then ?